# how to insert datetime into time(0) field

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing a bulk insert:

```
// Get the data into the DataTable
//dtData = GetData(...);

// Create an object of SqlBulkCopy
SqlBulkCopy objSBC = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
// Specify the destination table
objSBC.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
objSBC.BatchSize = 10000;
objSBC.DestinationTableName = "QuickLabDump";
// Write the data to the SQL Server

objSBC.WriteToServer(QuickLabDump);
```

my datatable that i am inserting looks like this:

```
QuickLabDump = new DataTable();

QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Time Collected", typeof(TimeSpan));
QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Time Entered", typeof(TimeSpan));
QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Time Completed", typeof(TimeSpan));
QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Test Time", typeof(TimeSpan));

QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Date Collected", typeof(DateTime));
QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Date Entered", typeof(DateTime));
QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Date Completed", typeof(DateTime));
QuickLabDump.Columns.Add("Test Date", typeof(DateTime));
......
```

When I run the bulk insert from c# (code above), I am getting the following error:

```
The given value of type DateTime from the data source cannot be converted to type time of the specified target column.
```

I think the problem is that I am inserting `typeof(DateTime)` into a sql server 2008 table that is `time(0)`

Here's a sample of the data that I am inserting:

```
6:50:00 AM
6:50:00 AM
6:50:00 AM
10:36:00 AM
4:45:00 PM
7:39:00 PM
```

**Question: how do I define a datatable column properly so that it will insert the above time values into a `time(0)` column?**

Here are values that already exist in the database table in the time(0) fields:

```
14:57:00
14:58:00
14:58:00
14:57:00
10:49:00
13:31:00
14:02:00
14:13:00
14:20:00
14:56:00
15:00:00
```

This is how I am adding data into `DataTable`:

```
 public DataTable dt;
        public ReadFileIntoDataTable(string inputfile)
        {
            using (GenericParserAdapter parser = new GenericParserAdapter())
            {
                parser.SetDataSource(inputfile);

                char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',' };
                parser.ColumnDelimiter = delimiters[0];
                parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
                //parser.SkipDataRows = 10;
                parser.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
                //parser.MaxRows = 500;
                parser.TextQualifier = '\"';

                dt = parser.GetDataTable();   


            }
```

Comment: You'll need to get rid of the AM/PM and convert the remaining string to a 24-hour time format (d.ToString("H:mm") where the capital "H" means 24-hour).

Comment: @RussellFox thanks so much i did this and for some reason getting the same error

Comment: good explaination., I try to see what could be the error..

Comment: Can you post the table definition from SQL Server?  In SQL Management Studio, right-click the table, then "Script Table As", then "Create To", then "Clipboard".  You should be able to paste it into your question, above (take out anything you consider confidential, of course!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created explicit column mappings between my datatable and the sql server table:

```
objSBC.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("datatable column name","sql server column name"));
```

for all columns.....
and that did the trick!!!

Comment: So your column names weren't right to start with? You shouldn't need to explicitly add a mapping - just make sure the column name is right in the data table. Again, a short but complete example including the SQL schema would have made this obvious much earlier.

Comment: the column names were all correct to begin with. for some reason when i added this explcit mapping it worked :) thank you so much for your patience with me

Comment: @Артём Царионов: Can you cut and paste your column mapping code into your answer then? Given the earlier mix-up between `user_name` and `name`, I'd be more inclined to suspect a similar foul-up than that an implicit column mapping was failing...

Answer (score 5):

Use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`. You can get a `TimeSpan` *from* a `DateTime` using [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx).

See the [SQL Server Data Type Mappings page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) for more type mapping information.

Comment: thanks so much now i am getting The given value of type DateTime from the data source cannot be converted to type time of the specified target column.

Comment: @Артём Царионов: You need to replace *all mention* of `DateTime` with `TimeSpan` for the columns involved.

Comment: thank you. i edited the question showing that i also have DATETIME columns in addition to timespan and still getting the same error

Comment: @Артём Царионов: Your question *only* shows what the types are in the `DataTable`. It doesn't show anything about the type in the database. Additionally, it would help if you'd isolate the problem to one field type or another. Create a sample database table with just a time field, then another with just a datetime field. Work on each separately until you're clear about how you're meant to handle them. That will make it easier to help you, apart from anything else.

Comment: the question is why is it trying to convert DATETIME to TIMESPAN during the insert?

Comment: the columns in the db are time(0) and datetime

Comment: @Артём Царионов: Which line is throwing the exception? It could be the way you're adding the data to the table, which you haven't shown...

Comment: this line is throwing exception objSBC.WriteToServer(QuickLabDump);

Comment: @Артём Царионов: That code doesn't really help us - it's just copying from one DataTable to another. We still don't know what's in the original DataTable, or how it got there. I suspect you've got DateTime values which should be TimeSpan values, but you haven't given us enough information to see...

Comment: And GenericParserAdapter is? I'm sorry, I haven't got time to spoon-feed you questions for diagnostics that you should be able to work out for yourself. Find out what the types are in the DataTable. If they're wrong, work out why they're wrong. Make sure *everything* is right before you do the bulk insert. If that doesn't help, write a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: appreciate your time, jon, but it's obvious that the problem is not with reading data into the datatable, the problem is during the bulkinsert

Comment: @Артём Царионов: If I had a pound for every time someone came to Stack Overflow absolutely *certain* that the problem wasn't in spot X, but it turned out to be there, I'd be rich. But hey, don't let my suggestions of conducting this in a rather more empirical way (testing each step on its own, with only one field at a time) get in the way.